# How to stop ubuntu machine from becoming vegetative

Tags: 11.10, server

I have a ubuntu server machine running 11.10 (not server edition) and sometimes when I do not do anything on the screen for a while, but I still use the services hosted on it from somewhere else on the local network, the machine suddenly goes into a coma. When I say a coma, I mean that the power light is on, the USB devices and CD drive have power and the fan is spinning, but the CPU light does not flash at all and it is not reachable over wired or wireless network, and the USB mouse and keyboard fail to wake it up. It is an "HP Compaq dc-7700 Small Form Factor" with an Intel Pentium D 3 GHz Dual Core CPU and Intel Incorporated Graphics chip.

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer that question with so little information. Is it reproduceable? That is, if you leave if for a certain amount of time, does it happen every time? How long does it take?

Comment: maybe your computer does not implement / support suspend mode S3 correctly and the system automatically suspends. Maybe try to disable suspend somewhere in the energy options.

Comment: I can't accurately test how long it takes and if it happens every time because I have school most days and on weekends it is used often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this as it has not happened for over a month, so whatever I did in between stopped it from happening. Maybe it was a buggy security update or something. We'll never know :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how server machine works but you shoul try to search after sleeping pc when inactive or something like that. I'm pretty sure that there is the problem.

Comment: it's not just sleeping though.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Power icon in the top row of the screen, and select **Power Settings...**. This will let you configure your system to "Suspend when inactive" for 5, 10, 30, 60 minutes or "Don't suspend".

Comment: already on don't suspend. and when I suspend manually, I can always wake it up again the normal way.